# Accessing DOM from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I took a look at this question but I'm having trouble with accessing the current tab's DOM from the chrome extension on startup,

[Google Chrome Extension - Accessing The DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063015/google-chrome-extension-accessing-the-dom)

I have this in the popup page for the chrome extension,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, { }, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
});
```

and this in my content script,

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        sendResponse({ doc: document.body });    
    }
);
```

When I send a text response back it works, but when I try to send document or document.body, I don't get anything on the receiving end.

Answer (score 1):

[Message Passing](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) specifies that `a message can contain any valid JSON object (null, boolean, number, string, array, or object)`. Instead of trying to send the document have the dom manipulation code in the `content_script`.