# Get tab's DOM using content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a script in my popup.html:

```
 </body>
 <script src="popup.js"></script>
 </html>
```

Through which I am trying to obtain the DOM of a particular tab. More specifically, I am attempting to determine the existence of a particular element on the current page in a specific tab and then use this information within popup.js. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063015/google-chrome-extension-accessing-the-dom

Answer (score 1):

You can't access current page DOM from a popup. You need a content script for that. Start by setting up these three scripts:

- popup script
- [background page script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

With these you can send messages between popup script and content script using background script as a proxy. Read about message passing [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

You can simplify the process a bit using [executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) instead a content script. You will still need a communication between popup script and a background page though.